# How to rename files using F2 on Windows XP, without the extension being selected?

Tags: windows-xp, rename, sp3

On Windows Vista & 7, when you select a file and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, only the file name is automatically selected *without spanning the extension*. Then you can write the new file name and hit enter. It is a useful feature as you don't have to select the file name apart from the extension by hand. On the other hand, Windows XP behaves old fashioned by selecting both file name and extension. Is it possible to do this by tweaking the registry of XP?

Note: Please do not propose to hide extensions for known file types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)** is of course again a possible answer to this question :-) .

LifeHacker had an article about exactly this issue: [**Mimic Vista's File Rename Feature in XP**](http://lifehacker.com/355580/mimic-vistas-file-rename-feature-in-xp)

It's available as the AutoHotkey source script or as a compiled executable name "Better Rename".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a registry hack, but [xplorer²](http://zabkat.com/) renames files with F2 like this.

Answer (score 0):

I use successfully the freeware application "Pitaschio", try it , it works much better than any other application

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? How does it work, what does it do, how would it do specifically what OP wants?