# How to select the whole file name?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select full file name when renaming on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/114869/select-full-file-name-when-renaming-on-windows-7)

When I select a file in the file explorer and press <kbd>F2</kbd> I get the file name highlighted, but not including the extension:

[image: File name selected after pressing F2]

Is there any way I can get the whole file name including extension selected without using third-party software (as opposed to this post: [Select full file name when renaming on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/114869/select-full-file-name-when-renaming-on-windows-7))? Or do I have to live with typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select the full file name.

Comment: Visit this answer for an AutoHotKey script
http://superuser.com/questions/114869/select-full-file-name-when-renaming-on-windows-7

Comment: @BrianA I am linking to that exact answer in my question. :)

Comment: @downvoter Please comment so that I know why this post is not useful.

Comment: This is one of those convenient features Microsoft added. You know, ones like hiding file extensions by default so you can't easily tell what kind of file you are looking at. Unfortunately, they didn't leave a checkbox to disable this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> when you want to select it all. Otherwise, use the command prompt

Comment: Not working on files located on Desktop! [ Windows.7.Ultimate.x64.May.2016 ]

Comment: Works on Windows 7 pro, and my copy of Ultimate 32 bit