# Is there a way to highlight the full file name, WITH extension, when renaming a file in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I think this feature was introduced with Vista: in the Explorer, when you shift to file renaming, the entire filename is selected by default, except the extension. This is surely a friendly feature to ensure you don't change the extension by mistake. I don't like this friendly feature. I want the whole file name selected, with extension, by default. It's there a way to do that?

Note: I'm not asking how to make extensions show. This issue appears even with extensions displayed.

Comment: What you can do as a work around, when the name gets highlighted, press Control A (select all), and get the name + extension quickly.

Comment: @Sickest I know. I'd like to avoid that. But thanks.

Comment: check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/114869/select-full-file-name-when-renaming-on-windows-7

Comment: @Sickest - Does it work the same in Win 8.1 as in Win 7?

Comment: no idea, try it out.

Answer (score -1):

Open File Explorer. Click the little up arrow at the top of the windows to make the Ribbon visible. Go to the View tab in the Ribbon. In the Show/Hide group simply check the File Name Extensions box.
-hope this helps...

Comment: Sorry, please re-read the question. This is not about showing extensions.