# Windows Update for auto-complete filename in Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-update

OS: Windows XP SP3

Seems there is a Windows Update improves Explorer interface, adding auto-complete filename feature in open file dialogue, and when press F2 to rename file, the cursor will at filename(cursor here).txt instead of old way - filename.txt(cursor here). Does anyone know which update should I download? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to auto-complete [here](http://smallvoid.com/article/ie-autosuggest.html) by modifying registry. And Vista Style F2 rename in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/102104/renaming-files-using-f2-on-windows-xp). Also, the autohotkey script needs to add this code on the top, some how `CabinetWClass` doesn't work for WinXP SP3 explorer.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ExploreWClass
~F2::
Gosub, AnalyzeRename
return
```