# Is there a way to revert Windows 7/Vista F2 keypress behavior to XP's?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select full file name when renaming on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/114869/select-full-file-name-when-renaming-on-windows-7)

I am referring to the Windows 7 F2 keypress behavior that occurs when the focus is set to a file in Windows Explorer.  I would like to change its behavior back to the XP model of selecting the entire file name including the file extension.  Thanks.

Comment: The direct contrary: [Renaming files using F2 on Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/102104/renaming-files-using-f2-on-windows-xp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to copy the filename after pressing F2 you could check out [CopyFilenames](http://www.extrabit.com/copyfilenames/)

Comment: No, I am not, thanks.  I have dozens of macros I wrote in XP that expect an F2 to highlight the entire file name and extension so the extension can be analyzed and choices made accordingly.  I'd rather not re-write them is all.